# Passing multiple arguments in maven - ERROR : Unknown lifecycle phase

Tags: java, maven, terminal, arguments

So I am trying to run a maven project(Java) via terminal.
I use this command:

```
mvn exec:java -Dexec.mainClass="cy.ac.ucy.cs.epl425.OpenWeatherMap.OpenWeatherMapApplication" -Dexec.args=”-weatherForecast Nicosia”
```

And I get the following errors :

```
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  0.763 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2022-02-23T14:38:32+02:00
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Unknown lifecycle phase "Nicosia”". You must specify a valid lifecycle phase or a goal in the format <plugin-prefix>:<goal> or <plugin-group-id>:<plugin-artifact-id>[:<plugin-version>]:<goal>. Available lifecycle phases are: validate, initialize, generate-sources, process-sources, generate-resources, process-resources, compile, process-classes, generate-test-sources, process-test-sources, generate-test-resources, process-test-resources, test-compile, process-test-classes, test, prepare-package, package, pre-integration-test, integration-test, post-integration-test, verify, install, deploy, pre-clean, clean, post-clean, pre-site, site, post-site, site-deploy. -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/LifecyclePhaseNotFoundException
```

If I pass only just one argument, then it runs fine. However I need to pass multiple arguments for some methods.

Comment: This will perhaps help you - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49091834/passing-multiple-arguments-to-maven

Comment: I tried it before posting and it didn't work for me. Thank you though

Comment: Your `-Dexec.args=”-weatherForecast Nicosia”` has broken quotation marks. Try `-Dexec.args="-weatherForecast Nicosia"`

Comment: Thank you very much , it worked that was the problem .