# How to Pass parameters with special characters to Maven Build from command line

Tags: maven

To pass parameters containing a list to a Maven build from command line, we can use the "-D" option and pass the values as a comma separated. Maven internally converts this into List, and uses down the line. This has been answered in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44686454/4894257).

However, if the parameters I try to pass has comma (or any other special character like brackets) in them, how should I pass them?

**Eg:** I need to pass the following 3 strings from command line to Maven build. 
In the pom it can be done as:

```
<argsList>
    <arg>Hello</arg>
    <arg>Hello, Hi</arg>
    <arg>Hello (Rohan, Ryan), Hi!</arg>
</argsList>
```

How do I pass these with the "-D" option? I tried encasing inside single...

```
mvn compile -Dmyproperty='Hello','Hello, Hi', 'Hello (Rohan, Ryan), Hi!'
```

and double quotes,

```
mvn compile -Dmyproperty="Hello","Hello, Hi", "Hello (Rohan, Ryan), Hi!"
```

but both fail.

Comment: does this help? https://www.logicbig.com/tutorials/apache-maven/java-compiler-arguments.html

Comment: I can set them in the pom. But I need to pass these from the command line, so that I can keep the pom generic..

Comment: Sorry I had a brain fart on that one. Check out the accepted answer on this one. basically you quote the entire -D, not just the value. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7513319/passing-command-line-arguments-from-maven-as-properties-in-pom-xml/33807842

Comment: For which plugins do you try to give those things via command line? Apart from that I would hardly think about this if it is really necessary...

Comment: @Stephan - Thanks! But I already did try that way. There too the parameters are split into the list based on the comma. Hence I finally get a list like this - `"Hello", "Hello", "Hi", "Hello (Rohan" , "Ryan)", "Hi!"`. Is this splitting Maven's default behavior? Can we modify this somehow? Thanks.

Comment: @khmarbaise - It is a custom plugin which I am working on.